# How can I find my pay period number using a date in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm keeping track of my time card and pay periods in google sheets, and I'd like to automatically fill the 'Pay Period' column based on the date of the shift I'm recording.

| Date | Pay Period |
| --- | --- |
| 10/30/23 | 13 |
| 11/02/23 | ? |

I have a separate sheet which contains the details of each pay period, including columns for the start and end dates. I want to take the Pay Period number where the date of x shift is **between** the start and end dates.

| Pay Period | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 10/30/23 | 11/12/23 |
| 14 | 11/13/23 | 11/26/23 |

So, for example, to fill in the unknown value in the first table, I would want to use the date (11/02/23) of the shift and find the pay period number where that date is between the start and end dates (10/30/23 and 11/12/23). So, the formula would return the number 13.

So far, I have this:

`=IF(ISBETWEEN(A33, LOOKUP(L32, 'Pay Statements'!A:A, 'Pay Statements'!B:B), LOOKUP(L32, 'Pay Statements'!A:A, 'Pay Statements'!C:C)), L32, L32+1)`

Where

A33 = the date of a given shift,
L32 = the previous shift's pay period number,
Pay Statements A:A contains pay period numbers,
Pay Statements B:B contains start dates,
Pay Statements C:C contains end dates

This formula checks if the date is between the **previous** shift's pay period start date and end date. If so, it uses the same number, and if not, it adds 1 (moves on to the next pay period).

This is working, but only assuming that I will have at least one shift every pay period. I would like it to work based on the actual dates and not just the previous shift. Also, I feel like this giant formula is not the most efficient way to accomplish this.

Comment: This is not a programming question (at least, not how this site defines them). You may get a better response on https://superuser.com (a sibling site to this one). The `google-sheets` tag is meant for help programmatically interacting with Google sheets, not for help with writing formulas.

Answer (score 0):

## Formula in `F2`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   LOOKUP(
     TOCOL(E2:E, 1), B2:B, A2:A))
```

## Sample Data and Results

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Period** | **Start Date** | **End Date** |  | **Lookup Date** | **Pay Period** |
| **2** | 13 | 10/30/23 | 11/12/23 |  | 10/30/23 | **`13`** |
| **3** | 14 | 11/13/23 | 11/26/23 |  | 11/03/23 | **`13`** |
| **4** |  |  |  |  | 11/14/23 | **`14`** |

## Explanation

1. For each date in `E2:E`, LOOKUP finds the date in `B2:B` that is closest without being greater, then returns the value in the same row of `A2:A`
2. The end dates of each week are not required in the formula since they are inferred from the next start date.
3. The lookup table of **Periods** and **Start Dates** must stay sorted in ascending order, if not sorting must be performed in the formula.

## Functions

[ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) [LOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256570?hl=en) [TOCOL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258?hl=en)